# Using different pallet racks in a process flow with an id for every pallet rack

Tags: anylogic

I would like to use different pallet racks in one process flow. So that I give my pallets an ID and connect it with a database. I decide in which pallet rack my pallets have to store from my forklifts. Is this possible?
And how could I do this? It doesnt work to give the pallet racks an ID and connect it with the database where I insert my pallets into source block.
Rack store and rack pick should know which pallet rack head for.

[image: process]

Answer (score 0):

Simply switch the Pallet rack choice to the dynamic mode and write some custom condition as below. If it is true, you use `palletRack`, else you use `palletRack1`.

`someCondition` must be boolean, obviously.

[image]

You can make this as complex as you like (any number of racks, any detail for your condition). For this, you might want to create your own function `getMyPalletRack` that takes some decisive arguments and returns a `PalletRack`. Then, call that in the "Pallet rack/Rack system" field instead.